# The British pronunciation of the word "schedule"

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, pronunciation-vs-spelling

Is pronouncing the word "schedule" as "shed-ule" only an upper class thing in the UK? Which pronunciation, "sked-ule" "or "shed-ule" is more faithful to the original etymology of the word, i.e. which came first?

Comment: I heard a very snide remark once, but I cannot remember if the person was a British or US native speaker: "I learned to say 'sked-yul' in school. Where did you learn to say 'shed-yule'? In shool?"

Comment: "Shed-ule" is the only British pronunciation I'm aware of and deeply upsets my US workmates when I use it, but I just can't help myself... sorry:-)

Comment: I'm from South Africa and our English is based on British English. I think about the words *scheme, school, schism* and it seems to me the word *schedule* should have the same rules applied to it and should be pronounced in a similar way.

Comment: @DylanJB: Rules? In English?

Comment: @teylyn - I guess its the same with tom-ay-toe v tom-ar-toe (cf potato)

Comment: @teylyn: :), but your pronunciation 'shool' = /ʃu:l/ is the same as the Yiddish-English 'schul' for synagogue. What is said for same in the UK, I don't know. 'sch-' can sometimes be pronounced 'sk-' in AmE  for latinate derivatives (e.g.'scholastic'). Also, there are the 'sch-/sk-' alternates shirt/skirt, ship/skiff, shell/scale, where the first is usually older (from OE, and the latter a more recent borrowing).

Comment: @ukayer I don't mind schedule, in fact I quite like the British pronunciation. Aluminum on the other hand...

Comment: @scleaver - but we (Brits) do have that whole extra 'i' in our spelling.  Makes all the difference.

Comment: On this Accent Tag video a native UK speaker from London uses "sked"-ule  .... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dxWXl1ZABhU    ... she also says "lyootenant", not "leftenant" for lieutenant, so she must watch lots of American TV

Comment: English pronunciation: UK vs.US. I am conversant with both and switch one with the other as the situation and/or context demands. However,  I refuse to misuse the words äwesome" and "like" which is more than can be said for the majority of our friends in the US.  I regret to say that the Brits are starting to mangle our shared language in this way.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=schedule):

> [...] the modern British pronunciation ("shed-yul") is from French influence, while the U.S. pronunciation ("sked-yul") is from the practice of Webster, and is based on the Greek original.

To answer your question directly, the modern spelling appeared in 15c as a throwback to the Latin *schedula*. Google's pronunciation of Latin *schedula* sounds like skeh-doo-la to me. This is closer to the typical US pronunciation.

The pronunciation guides I checked list the UK pronunciation as simply "UK". Whether it has a class distinction isn't something I can answer.

Comment: Elsewhere it says that *schedule* is related to the verb *shed* and noun *schism*, and so as long as you pronounce it like either of those (to pronounce it like both simultaneously would be hard), you should be fine.

Answer (score 10):

I've never been aware of a class distinction aspect of shed-yul vs. sked-yul.

I will note that the American pronunciation has made its way back over the pond to some extent. If that is due to the influence of film and TV (which I imagine it is) then it could well vary over different demographics.

Comment: I'm about as far from upper class as you can get and it's shed-ule

Comment: Yeah, I would say that shed-djul seems to be the dominant pronunciation around here.

Answer (score 6):

The earliest English pronunciation of *schedule* is no longer used, as far as I know: it was something like /ˈsɛdjul/ (compare *schism,* which some still pronounce as “sizm”).

The OED says

> In the 16th cent., both in French and English, the spellings *scedule* and *schedule,* imitating the contemporary forms of the Latin word, were used by a few writers. In French this fashion was transient, but in English *schedule* has been the regular spelling from the middle of the 17th cent. The original pronunciation /ˈsɛdjuːl/ continued in use long after the change in spelling; it is given in 1791 by Walker without alternative; in his second ed. (1797) he says that it is ‘too firmly fixed by custom to be altered’, though on theoretical grounds he would prefer either /ˈskɛdjuːl/, favoured by Kenrick, Perry, and Buchanan, or—‘if we follow the French’— /ˈʃɛdjuːl/. The latter he does not seem to have known either in actual use or as recommended by any orthoepist. Smart, however, in 1836 gives /ˈʃɛdjuːl/ in the body of his Dictionary without alternative, although in his introduction he says that as the word is of Greek origin the normal pronunciation would be with /sk/. Several later Dicts. recognize /ˈsɛdjuːl/ as permissible, but it is doubtful whether this was really justified by usage. In England the universal pronunciation at present seems to be with /ʃ/; in the U.S., the authority of Webster has secured general currency for /sk/.

It seems from this that /sk/ may be slightly earlier than /ʃ/, at least as a theoretical pronunciation for use in English, since Walker 1797 references earlier mentions of /sk/ by Kenrick, Perry, and Buchanan, while it was possibly his own idea to look at French (pronunciation rules?) for /ʃ/. (It's true that modern words in French spelled with *sch-* are pronounced /ʃ/, such as *schéma,* and as the OED mentions there are examples of "sch" being used in an obsolete spelling variant of this word in French—I found an example here [from the early 1700s](https://books.google.com/books?id=aHRZAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA517&lpg=PA517&dq=%22s%C3%A7avoir%22%20schedule&source=bl&ots=Lk00QufIsj&sig=HVnxU76E-M_RTPgaCvXjgBEvRVI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjMzfzvstfTAhUpwYMKHUKUAWA4ChDoAQgyMAI#v=onepage&q=%22s%C3%A7avoir%22%20schedule&f=false)—but it’s not clear to me that Walker had any actual contact with a French speaker who used /ʃ/, or the "sch" spelling, in his time). Overall, it doesn't seem entirely clear to me which pronounciation, /sk/ or /ʃ/, can be considered to have become established earlier than the other.

The Latin source word seems to have a somewhat obscure etymology; however, I thought a brief discussion of it might provide some useful context for the various pronunciations.

### Etymology

It seems solidly established that the word comes from medieval Latin *schedula/scedula,* a diminutive form of a word *scheda/scida* meaning “a strip of papyrus”. This was apparently related in some fashion to a Greek word *σχέδη/σχίδη,* although the direction of transfer isn’t entirely clear:

> Lat. *schedula,* a small leaf of paper ; dimin. of scheda, also *scida* (Cicero, Att. i. 20 *fin.*) a strip of papyrus-bark. β The Greek *σχέδη,* a tablet, leaf, may have been borrowed from Lat. *scheda* (or *sceda* ?) see Liddell; but we find also Greek *σχίδη,* a cleft piece of wood, a splint, which looks like the original of Latin *scida.* The difficulty is to know whether the Lat. word is original (from *scid-,* base of *scindere*) or borrowed (from Gr. *σχίζειυ,* to cleave). Either way, it is from √SKID, to cleave: cf. Skt. *chhid,* to cut.

– *[An Etymological Dictionary of the English Language](https://books.google.com/books?id=A4M_AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA530&lpg=PA530&dq=scheda%20etymology&source=bl&ots=LF9yD0e0B3&sig=k12muN6MLoWOymirEmKHTnlS2Zs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOi5u_pNfTAhXnlFQKHQl9BIMQ6AEITDAJ#v=onepage&q=scheda%20etymology&f=false),*
by the Rev. Walter W. Skeat, 1882. (I know this is an old source, but it’s the most complete description of the etymology that I could find out of the sources available to me.) If this etymology is correct, it would in fact mean that the the word is related to the English verb *shed* (as [Henry said in a comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24035/the-british-pronunciation-of-the-word-schedule#comment40452_24036)) but extremely distantly, so this wouldn't be expected to be relevant to the present-day English pronunciation.

In Greek, there is a difference between the pronunciation of κ (“c/k”) and χ (“ch”). The first corresponds to the voiceless velar plosive /k/; the second corresponded in early stages of Greek to an aspirated velar plosive /kʰ/, and in later and modern Greek corresponds  to a voiceless velar fricative /x/.

In Latin, the digraph “ch” was originally used to represent χ in loans from Greek, and educated speakers likely pronounced it as /kʰ/, distinct from “c”. Later on, “ch” came to be used as an alternative to “c” in some native Latin words, such as “pulcher”; it is hypothesized that [this might have been related to some phonetic development in these words](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/647/were-th-and-ch-aspirated-in-classical-latin). In even later Latin writing (e.g. in the medieval times), we see even more variation between “c” and “ch” (or “t” and “th”), which suggests that at some point, either one could be used to represent the same consonant /k/. Sometimes false etymologies from Greek also contributed to the use of “h” digraphs in the spelling of Latin words: the word “amarantus” came to be spelled “amaranthus” by association with the Greek word ἄνθος (anthus) “flower”.

- So, regardless of the word’s origin, it seems likely that /sk/ was used in its Latin pronunciation at some point. Scholars have been aware of this for a while, and this is the basis for the /sk/ pronunciation in English.
- The sound /k/ ended up being fronted before front vowels in the development from Latin to Romance languages. In French, the final outcome of this was /s/, and this pronunciation of the letter "c" was used even in learned words, which is why "cédule" was pronounced /sedyl/. This is the origin of the original pronunciation used in English with /s/ and no /k/.
- In French, the digraph "ch" came to be used to represent the /ʃ/ sound resulting from another palatalization of /k/, and this caused many learned borrowings from Latin and Greek that were spelled with "ch", such as the word *schéma* that I mentioned earlier, to have pronunciations with /ʃ/ based on the spelling. (Since /*sʃ/ is not a possible word-initial consonant cluster in French, it's natural for *sch-* to be interpreted as /ʃ/). This seems to be what Walker (1797) viewed as the basis for a possible pronunciation with /ʃ/.

In addition to this, I have a suspicion that the graphical similarity of "sh" and "sch", and the use of "sch" for /ʃ/ in German, may have also reinforced the /ʃ/ pronunciation of this word in English.

Comment: Today, the older the British speaker is, the more likely they will say "shed-yule", and I do think it's a middle-class / grammar school thing. https://youglish.com/pronounce/schedule/english/uk?