# Is the varying pronunciation of "schedule" using "sh-" vs "sk-" regional or individual?

Tags: pronunciation, dialects, phonology, transatlantic-differences, register

## ‘Hard’ /ˈskɛ.djuːl/
vs ‘Soft’ /ˈʃɛ.djuːl/

Is one of the two variants

1. **/ˈʃɛ.djuːl/** with ‘sh‑’
    (so including [ˈʃɛ.djɫ], [ˈʃɛ.dʒɫ̩], [ˈʃɛ.dʒu.əɫ], [ˈʃɛ.dʒuːɫ])
2. **/ˈskɛ.djuːl/** with ‘sk‑’
    (so including [ˈskɛ.dʒu.əɫ], [ˈskɛ.djɫ̩], [ˈskɛ.dʒuɫ],
   [ˈskɛ.dʒuːɫ], [ˈskɛˌdʒuɫ], [ˈskɛ.dʒʊɫ], [ˈskɛ.dʒəɫ])

more widespread in the US vs UK, or is this just a matter of areas or even single individuals?

Comment: Related: [The British pronunciation of the word 'schedule'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24035/the-british-pronunciation-of-the-word-schedule/387854#387854).

Comment: /skɛdjuːl/ is the only pronunciation in the US, in all areas.  /ˈʃɛdjuːl/ sounds very British to me. I don't know what they do in Australia, India, or elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks @EdwinAshworth I hadn't seen that one...

Comment: The starting sound /sk/ is indeed the pronunciation used in the US, but the second consonant cluster can be more like /dʒj/.

Comment: It may not simply be another difference between US and Br English. When I dealt with legislation as a civil servant in the UK in the 1970s and 1980s we all said /ˈʃɛdjuːl/. My flatmate at that time, a barrister of mixed Irish/Scottish ancestry, always said /skɛdjuːl/ .

Comment: Yes, when I lived in London some time ago /ˈʃɛdjuːl/. was definitely the more used version.